# How to check if all items in collection have a specific property value?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to check if all items in my collection have a specific property value, suppose that I've a property called `IsFavourite`, I need to check if this property is true for each element. I tried this:

```
var c = listView.Items.Cast<Event>().Where(x => x.MatchNation == nation 
        && x.MatchLeague == league && x.IsFavourite == true).Any();
```

but this will return only a single item that have this property.

Comment: Change `Any()` to `All()`, also you don't need the `== true`, you can simply write `&& x.IsFavourite`.

Comment: Just use `All` instead of `Any`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `All()`

```
bool result = listView.Items.Cast<Event>()
                      .Where(x => x.MatchNation == nation && x.MatchLeague == league)
                      .All(x => x.IsFavourite);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `Any()`, but you check if any items is not IsFavourite (`IsFavourite==false`).

```
var z = listView.Items.OfType<Event>().Where(x => x.MatchNation == nation 
            && x.MatchLeague == league).Any(x => x.IsFavourite==false);
```

Comment: But you have to change the variable name, for example change `allAreFavourites` to `anyNonFavourite`. The meaning is different.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `All`

```
var c = listView.Items.OfType<Event>().Where(x => x.MatchNation == nation 
        && x.MatchLeague == league).All(x => x.IsFavourite);
```